# Parse a log file, match against string array

Tags: powershell

I have a very large DNS bebug log, where each line contains an IP and a record type (SOA, A, PTR) separated by spaces.
An example:

```
SND    2.2.2.2    SOA
SND  2.2.2.2  A
RCV   11.11.11.11    A
RCV  4.4.4.4       SOA
RCV    7.7.7.7   SOA
```

I want to filter out any lines that contain the word SOA, or contain any of the values from the $IgnoreIPs string array. How can I do this?

```
   $LogFilePath = (Get-content "c:\DNS Debug.log" )
    $IgnoreIps= "1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3","4.4.4.4"

       foreach ($Line in $LogFilePath){
          if (($Line -match "Rcv") -and ($line -notmatch "SOA") -and ($line -notmatch $IgnoreIps)){
               write-host "do stuff"
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this easier parsing each line into it's individually meaningful components:

```
foreach($line in $LogFilePath){

  # Split into three parts, trim any trailing whitespace
  $direction,$address,$rtype = $Line -split '\s+',3 |% Trim

  if($address -in $IgnoreIps){
    # ignored IP, skip this line
    continue
  }

  if($rtype -eq 'SOA'){
    # SOA record, skip this line
    continue
  }

  if($direction -eq 'Rcv'){
    # Neither address nor resource type is ignored, let's do the work!
    Write-Host "do stuff"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The log file is not actually in that format, it's got about 16 columns (with lots of spaces in the actual column value)... so splitting it into variables doesn't work that easily - but I ended up  putting in the -notin condition in a nested if statement (see update in original post)

Comment: @Aziz I don't see why you couldn't parse all 16 columns (whether into spearate variables or some other data structure) - but I can't really speak to what you _didn't_ include in your question :-)

Comment: Appreciate what you're saying, it would be more efficient to parse the log files into an object with each column being  a property....but this is quick and dirty, just need to get it done :)

Comment: @Aziz Fair enough, to each their own. If I can ask you a favor: please post your solution as an actual answer, below - that way the question is not listed as "unanswered" (you'll get rep for accepting it too!) :-)

Comment: Learned some useful knowledge from this answer.  Had no idea we could assign multiple variables in one go.  `$a, $b, $c = 1..10`  Fun stuff.  Thank you sir!

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE - Not the most elegant, but I ended up doing this:
Not the most elegant way to do it, but this works (notin operator):

```
foreach ($Line in $LogFilePath){
    if ( ($Line -match "Rcv") -and !(($Line -match 'SOA') -or ($Line -match 'TKEY')) ){
        $IPAddress = ($Line| Select-String -Pattern "\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
            If($IPAddress -notin $IgnoreIps){  
                write-host "do stuff"

            }
    }
}
```